# Boost.Log linking errors under GNU/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I would like to test the Boost.Log library. Unfortunately, I get link errors.

I use Arch Linux, and I installed Boost headers and libraries via built-in package manager `pacman`:

- boost 1.54.0-3
- boost-libs 1.54.0-2

When compiling the simple example from [official site](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial.html) via `g++ log.cpp -lboost_log -lpthread`, I get the following errors:

```
log.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()'
log.cpp:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()'
...
```

I've read [Why my application fails to link with Boost.Log?](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html), but I couldn't solve the link errors. It only gives me the hint that the library where `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()` is in was linked statically. But under directory `/usr/lib/` there are only dynamically linked Boost libraries with extension `.so`.

Maybe, someone has a clue what's going wrong here.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [linker error while linking boost log tutorial (undefined references)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137637/linker-error-while-linking-boost-log-tutorial-undefined-references)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to define [BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html):

```
g++ -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK blog.cpp -lboost_log -lpthread
```

Comment: Why is this macro necessary ?

Comment: It's all expained in the documentation linked in the answer. In short, Boost.Log uses an internal namespace for its implementation. Your application makes use of it by simply using Boost.Log. By default, Boost.Log assumes you're using a static version of the library, and attempts to use `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix`. The `s` in `v2s` stands for "static". Defining `BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` instructs Boost.Log to look for `boost::log::v2_mt_posix` instead (notice, no `s` in `v2_mt`), which is the correct namespace to use if you have a dynamic log library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `cmake` then:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system log)
target_link_libraries(credential ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_LOG_LIBRARY})
```

and use:

```
#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK 1
```