# linking boost log using cmake error

Tags: c++, logging, boost, cmake

what can cause the following problem: 
I tried to use boost::log in a cmake project.

My CMakeList.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(boostLogTest)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(boostLogTest main.cpp)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK) #####  edit after DiCri's answer #####
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS log system)

if (Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    message("Boost VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")
    message("Boost INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message("Boost Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
    message("Boost LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(boostLogTest ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif ()
```

and my main.cpp file looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

My CMake output is the following

> -- Boost version: 1.64.0
>
> -- Found the following Boost libraries:
>
> --   log
>
> --   system
>
> --   date_time
>
> --   log_setup
>
> --   filesystem
>
> --   thread
>
> --   regex
>
> --   chrono
>
> --   atomic Boost VERSION: 106400 Boost INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/local/include Boost Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: /usr/local/lib Boost
>
> LIBRARIES:
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so;/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so;/usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.so;/usr/local/lib/libboost_log_setup.so;/usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so;/usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.so;/usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.so;/usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic.so
>
> -- Configuring done
>
> -- Generating done
>
> -- Build files have been written to: /home/.../CLionProjects/boostLogTest/cmake-build-debug

but while linking I get the following error messages:

> [ 50%] Linking CXX executable boostLogTest
>
> CMakeFiles/boostLogTest.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
>
> /home/.../CLionProjects/boostLogTest/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()'
>
> /home/.../CLionProjects/boostLogTest/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()'
>
> /home/.../CLionProjects/boostLogTest/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()'
>
> /home/.../CLionProjects/boostLogTest/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()'
>
> /home/.../CLionProjects/boostLogTest/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()'
>   CMakeFiles/boostLogTest.dir/main.cpp.o:/home/.../CLionProjects/boostLogTest/main.cpp:9: more undefined references to`boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()' follow ...

Edit after DiCri's answer: 
Now I get the following error messages:

> [ 50%] Linking CXX executable boostLogTest
>
> /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/boostLogTest.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_rwlock_unlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
>
> //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> CMakeFiles/boostLogTest.dir/build.make:103: recipe for target 'boostLogTest' failed
>
> make[3]: *** [boostLogTest] Error 1
>
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/boostLogTest.dir/all' failed
>
> make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/boostLogTest.dir/all] Error 2
>
> CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/boostLogTest.dir/rule' failed
>
> make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/boostLogTest.dir/rule] Error 2
>
> Makefile:118: recipe for target 'boostLogTest' failed
>
> make: *** [boostLogTest] Error 2

If I add

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
```

the paths to the libraries change to a *.a file, like:

```
Boost LIBRARIES: /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.a;/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a;...
```

All listed libraries (the *.so and the *.a) exist in this folders.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to add this line

```
#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK 1
```

As the first line of the main.cpp file, i think it should work, someone got your same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137637/linker-error-while-linking-boost-log-tutorial-undefined-references)

If that doesn't work, try to add this line

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK)
```

To CMake file
You need to add OpenMP package too

Comment: Thank you. I now get:
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable boostLogTest
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/boostLogTest.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_rwlock_unlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/boostLogTest.dir/build.make:103: recipe for target 'boostLogTest' failed

Comment: is there a way to set this in cmake?

Comment: Thank you for your hints. Now it is working. I simply added the OpenMP package, (which I need as well in my real application but was not used in this test of boost::log) and now everything works.

In summary a combination of 
`ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK)`
and using OpenMP worked

Comment: I updated the answer for who will have your same issue, so accept the answer and sign the topic as solved @user7431005