# linker error while linking boost log (undefined references to boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, linker

I’m trying to compile a program, which uses boost libraries on Ubuntu and I'm getting error:

```
stepan@stepan-System-Product-Name:~/dev$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK  -c test.cpp
stepan@stepan-System-Product-Name:~/dev$ g++  test.o  -lboost_log -lboost_thread -lpthread -lboost_system -o test
test.o: In function `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >& boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::formatted_write<wchar_t>(wchar_t const*, long)':
/usr/include/boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp:575: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, std::string&, std::locale const&)'
test.o: In function `void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::aligned_write<wchar_t>(wchar_t const*, long)':
/usr/include/boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp:696: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, std::string&, std::locale const&)'
/usr/include/boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp:702: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, std::string&, std::locale const&)'
test.o: In function `void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::feed_record<boost::recursive_mutex, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend>(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::recursive_mutex&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend&)':
/usr/include/boost/log/sinks/basic_sink_frontend.hpp:445: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::consume(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, std::string const&)'
test.o: In function `void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::feed_record<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::fake_mutex, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend>(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::fake_mutex&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend&)':
/usr/include/boost/log/sinks/basic_sink_frontend.hpp:445: undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::consume(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

stepan@stepan-System-Product-Name:~/dev$ g++ -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK test.cpp  -Wall -L$BOOST/lib/ -I $BOOST/include/ -pthread -lboost_system -lboost_log_setup -lboost_log -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lrt -lboost_filesystem
/tmp/cczxT0rE.o: In function `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >& boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::formatted_write<wchar_t>(wchar_t const*, long)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE15formatted_writeIwEERS6_PKT_l[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE15formatted_writeIwEERS6_PKT_l]+0xb2): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, std::string&, std::locale const&)'
/tmp/cczxT0rE.o: In function `void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::aligned_write<wchar_t>(wchar_t const*, long)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE13aligned_writeIwEEvPKT_l[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE13aligned_writeIwEEvPKT_l]+0xa2): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, std::string&, std::locale const&)'
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE13aligned_writeIwEEvPKT_l[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix24basic_formatting_ostreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE13aligned_writeIwEEvPKT_l]+0x12e): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert(wchar_t const*, unsigned long, std::string&, std::locale const&)'
/tmp/cczxT0rE.o: In function `void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::feed_record<boost::recursive_mutex, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend>(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::recursive_mutex&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS_15recursive_mutexENS2_17text_file_backendEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS_15recursive_mutexENS2_17text_file_backendEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_]+0x16b): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::consume(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, std::string const&)'
/tmp/cczxT0rE.o: In function `void boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::basic_formatting_sink_frontend<char>::feed_record<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::fake_mutex, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend>(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::fake_mutex&, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS1_3aux10fake_mutexENS2_17text_file_backendEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_[_ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix5sinks30basic_formatting_sink_frontendIcE11feed_recordINS1_3aux10fake_mutexENS2_17text_file_backendEEEvRKNS1_11record_viewERT_RT0_]+0x16b): undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::text_file_backend::consume(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view const&, std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code of test.cpp:

```
/*
 *          Copyright Andrey Semashev 2007 - 2013.
 * Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
 *    (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
 *          http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
 */
#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK 1
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

//[ example_tutorial_formatters_stream
void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",
        // This makes the sink to write log records that look like this:
        // 1: <normal> A normal severity message
        // 2: <error> An error severity message
        keywords::format =
        (
            expr::stream
                << expr::attr< unsigned int >("LineID")
                << ": <" << logging::trivial::severity
                << "> " << expr::smessage
        )
    );
}
//]

#if 0

//[ example_tutorial_formatters_stream_date_time
void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",
        // This makes the sink to write log records that look like this:
        // YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS: <normal> A normal severity message
        // YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS: <error> An error severity message
        keywords::format =
        (
            expr::stream
                << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                << ": <" << logging::trivial::severity
                << "> " << expr::smessage
        )
    );
}
//]

#endif

int main(int, char*[])
{
    init();
    logging::add_common_attributes();

    using namespace logging::trivial;
    src::severity_logger< severity_level > lg;

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

I tried this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK  -c test.cpp
g++  test.o  -lboost_log -lboost_thread -lpthread -lboost_system -lboost_log_setup -o test
```

And this:

```
g++ -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK test.cpp  -Wall -L$BOOST/lib/ -I $BOOST/include/ -pthread -lboost_system -lboost_log_setup -lboost_log -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lrt -lboost_filesystem
```

From responses to these questions:

[linker error while linking boost log tutorial (undefined references)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137637/linker-error-while-linking-boost-log-tutorial-undefined-references)

[Boost logger linking issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881602/boost-logger-linking-issue)

[Boost.Log linking errors under GNU/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419003/boost-log-linking-errors-under-gnu-linux)

Without success - the same error during linking and error message looks a bit different than in the questions above

Therefore, I assume that the root cause of my error is different from all mentioned above

Installed boost version 1.58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found a clue:
[image]
It looks like some files are left even after uninstalling of previous boost version 1.58 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

The issue was resolved after I deleted manually all libboost* files with exception for *.so.1.58.0 (see description below why) from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu left from the previous installation (my currently installed boost v 1.64 is in /usr/local):
[image]

Be aware that deleting of *. so. 1.58.0 files can make some apps not working (Firefox and chrome in my case), so I had to build boost v 1.58 and place them back to make them operational again

Comment: You're working with text files on a website that deals with text with people trying to help you by providing text. NEVER provide screenshots of text. That's a horrible thing to do in an environment like this.